# is it bad for design using nested derived classes

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I reading some code written by some other programmer, He made some design for application, application classes derived each other like that:

```
public interface IABase
{

}
class BBase : IABase
{

}

class CDesktop : BBase
{

}

class Report : CDesktop
{

}

class Sample : Report
{

}
```

This kind of design is anti pattern? I have to tell first, its realy hard to understand relationship of class and logic of application, this is my 2 cents. What else you can say?

Comment: The short answer is "it depends".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a bit of general advice floating around to prefer composition over inheritance.  The advantage often touted are that it's more flexible, and discourages tight coupling more.  (see [where-does-this-concept-of-favor-composition-over-inheritance-come-from](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65179/where-does-this-concept-of-favor-composition-over-inheritance-come-from), [DeepClassHierarchies](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DeepClassHierarchies), [deep-class-inheritance-hierarchy-bad-idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056943/deep-class-inheritance-hierarchy-bad-idea), [long-inheritance-hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193132/long-inheritance-hierarchy) amongst many others for discussions on this matter).

Specifically for C#, it's worth noting that composition can require considerable boilerplate - after all, if you want to expose much of the functionality of the component/base-class, then you'll need to manually expose that; inheritance (by contrast) makes it very easy to just expose everything.

It's probably a good idea to use inheritance sparingly when in doubt because it's easy to create lots of tightly coupled spagetti-monsters otherwise.  But there are cases where classical dynamic dispatch and all that is wanted; and there are also cases where even though your concepts better map to a has-a relationship than an is-a relationship the wordiness of composition is a considerable burden.

So while this kind of code is harder to maintain, it might still be worth it on occasion. Your specific example looks like the hierarchy is unnecessarily deep; however, it's normal for old code to grow a few warts - if this is the worst of it, consider yourself lucky.

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that if you're using inheritance because the API is just too big to manually pass on, well, that API is probably *too big*, period.  It can't always be helped, and unfortunately the .NET libraries themselves are bad examples to follow in this regard, but in general a small public surface area makes all kinds of things easier.